# Nestjs cronjob cannot read inject service

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, nestjs

I set up a cronjob that is supposed to fire and call a service from another module. console logged items are displaying in the console and When I run the method manually from the endpoint. The service returns a successful result. But once I put back the cronjob decorator. The service is undefined

throwing exception `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAll' of undefined`

I have used other nodejs cronjob packages, but the error persists. Is there a workaround?

```
@Cron(CronExpression.EVERY_10_SECONDS)
async test() {
  try {
    console.log('working 22');
    const ee = await this.Service.getAll();
    console.log(ee);
    for (const key in ee) {
      console.log(ee[key].termsID);
    }
    const terms = await this.termsModel.find({
      isDeleted: false
    });
    console.log(terms);
    console.log('working 22 end!');
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

appmodule

```
@Module({
  imports: [
   TermsModule,
    ScheduleModule.forRoot()
  ],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that you declare the service that you want to use from the global module in the `Cron`-Service's providers. Consider this simple example:

```
// Sample Cron-Service
// -------------
@Injectable()
export class CronService {

  private readonly logger = new Logger(CronService.name);

  constructor(private globalService: GlobalService) {
  }

  @Cron(CronExpression.EVERY_5_SECONDS)
  test() {
    this.logger.debug(`Called every 5 seconds with random value: ${this.globalService.getSomeData()}`);
  }
}

// Cron-Module
// -------------
@Module({
          providers: [CronService, GlobalService] // <--- this is important, you need to add GlobalService as a provider here
        })
export class CronModule {
}

// Global-Service
// -------------
@Injectable()
export class GlobalService {

  getSomeData() {
    return Math.random() * 500;
  }
}

// Global-Module
// -------------
@Global()
@Module({
          providers: [GlobalService]
        })
export class GlobalModule {
}
```

Also, you need to make sure that the global module is imported in your root/core module - along with the `ScheduleModule` from the `@nestjs/schedule` package, e.g.:

```
@Module({
          imports:     [GlobalModule, ScheduleModule.forRoot(), ... ]
        })
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: I created a separate different from the global service I have before so that I can call it normally like other modules that are injected, I have followed the steps but still not working

Comment: I am thinking of using setInterval

Comment: I don't unterstand your comment, sorry - you need to edit your question and add more code - I cannot help you otherwise ..

Comment: Also I would not recommend using `setInterval` if NestJS already offers more robust solutions ... pretty sure it's just a module-setup issue in your case.

Comment: I removed the cronjob decorator and ran the service from the controller, I was able to call the service and it was successful. I don't know why cronjob cannot call the same service

Comment: Are you importing `ScheduleModule.forRoot()` in your root module as I did in my example?

Comment: Yes, I have done that, I was having it in the cronJob module before and I have removed it

Comment: I tried what you did, I got ```
message:'Cannot read property 'debug' ```

Comment: You need to import the Logger from `import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';` ...

Comment: Yes, I have this already ```import { Logger, Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";```

Comment: Here's a sandbox with a minimal example that should help you out: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-violet-segu9?file=/src/main.ts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221355/discussion-between-techstack-and-eol).